# Map a number to an id in python

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a numpy array like: [11, 30, 25]. These numbers represent categories of the objects corresponding to the indices. I know there are just 20 categories but for some reason they are numbered from 11 to 29. I'd like to convert them to numbers in 0:19 and back. What would by a pythonic way to do this? Preferably in bumpy.

EDIT: this is just a small example of a bigger problem, where the number of categories are in the thousands, and some categories are never represented, so the maximum id will be the number of unique existing categories.

Comment: Subtract `11` from them?

Comment: Just to top @Divakar: subtract `my_array.min()` ;)

Comment: @Divakar is that only 0~18?

Comment: Now that you've edited your question, it's no longer trivial. It's unclear instead.

Comment: would an `sklearn` solution be ok?

Comment: any solution would be fine

Comment: the question is, if it is unique, what is compelling you to convert them as zero indexed ? You can always enumerate or figure out another way to iterate

Comment: @karthikr I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: See if this works for you : `np.unique(input_array,return_inverse=True)`. This would ID each category starting from 0 until `N-1`, where `N` is the number of categories.

Comment: @Divakar that does the conversion from the categories to id. How would I go from id to categories?

Comment: This is either getting surreal or I have no idea what is going on.

Comment: say now I have a new array containing categories and a new array containing ids. How do I convert one to the other, given the ```unique``` and ```inverse``` arrays from ```np.unique```?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be able to easily convert back-and-forth, I would use the `sklearn.preprocessing` module `LabelEncoder`:

```
In [7]: from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

In [8]: encoder = LabelEncoder()

In [9]: encoder.fit(range(11,31))
Out[9]: LabelEncoder()

In [10]: encoder.transform([11,30,25])
Out[10]: array([ 0, 19, 14])

In [11]: encoder.inverse_transform([18, 1, 15])
Out[11]: array([29, 12, 26])
```

Comment: This one is elegant but it makes my ipython notebook kernel die. I have about 10000 categories.

Answer (score 5):

Let's say `arr` is the input array of categories.

**Forward Process/Encoding :** From categories to IDs

To perform the encoding, use `np.unique` alongwith its optional `return_inverse` argument to give us IDs that would have values from `0` to `N-1`, where `N` is the number of categories you would have in `arr` , like so -

```
unq,idx = np.unique(arr,return_inverse=True)
```

**Backward Process/Decoding :** From IDs to categories

To go back to the original categories from the `IDs (idx)`, just index into unique categories saved earlier as `unq`, like so -

```
arr_out = unq[idx]
```

Sample run -

```
In [40]: arr # Input array of categories
Out[40]: array([7, 1, 1, 3, 8, 2, 7, 7, 0, 2])

In [41]: unq,idx = np.unique(arr,return_inverse=True)

In [42]: idx  # ID array with values from 0 to 5 (6 categories)
Out[42]: array([4, 1, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 4, 0, 2])

In [43]: unq[idx] # Get back original array of categories
Out[43]: array([7, 1, 1, 3, 8, 2, 7, 7, 0, 2])
```